# How to select option by ID from parent controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

## Summary

What's a clean way of updating a `select` element in a child controller scope so that the selected item's ID matches an ID in a parent scope?

## Details

I have two controllers:

- `OrderController`
- `CustomerController`

`OrderController` loads an Order and shows it on an order form.

`CustomerController` is the scope for a subform within the `OrderController` form. It shows a list of all customers, with the default customer being the one associated with the order. The user can edit the details of the selected customer or add a customer right from the subform.

## Possible Solutions

I've thought of two so far, but neither seems very good.

1. Include a list of all customers in the JSON passed to the Order `$resource`. That won't work because the user needs a full separate controller to update customers on the subform.
2. Fire an event when the customers have loaded within CustomerController. OrderController handles that event, updating the `select` based on its order's `customer_id` property. That seems better but still hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To communicate between two controllers you would usually broadcast/emit, e.g:

(Coffeescript)

CustomerController:

```
Api.Customer.get(
  id: $scope.customer_id
).$promise.then (data) ->
  $scope.$emit 'event:updateOptionId', id
```

OrderController:

```
$scope.$on 'event:updateOptionId', (event, id) ->
  $scope.customer_id = id
```

I don't know the structure of your app but this is passing the new customer id to order controller based on an action in the customer controller. If you post some of your code you may get a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Angular does handle the update automatically. The problem was that my server was returning a one-item array for the order data. So the customer_id of the order property wasn't going into `$scope.order.customer_id`; it was going into `$scope.order[0].customer_id`. Correcting that on the back end solved the issue.